# Thymeleaf Table Rows Divide in separate Pages

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have table with 212 rows and I would like to split them between pages so that all pages have 25 rows and last page 12 rows. 
I would like to know if this is possible at all with Thymeleaf or should I use something else for that.
And is it possible to calculate total values per page also?

Here is the pdf file: https://www.docdroid.net/TSLdFA1/report1.pdf

Comment: controller should provide view with 25 rows of data and corresponding pagination data. and view should render table and pagination navigator.

Answer (score 0):

the is sample code for the controller

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

@Autowired
private BookService bookService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/listBooks", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listBooks(
  Model model, 
  @RequestParam("page") Optional<Integer> page, 
  @RequestParam("size") Optional<Integer> size) {
    int currentPage = page.orElse(1);
    int pageSize = size.orElse(5);

    Page<Book> bookPage = bookService.findPaginated(PageRequest.of(currentPage - 1, pageSize));

    model.addAttribute("bookPage", bookPage);

    int totalPages = bookPage.getTotalPages();
    if (totalPages > 0) {
        List<Integer> pageNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, totalPages)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        model.addAttribute("pageNumbers", pageNumbers);
    }

    return "listBooks.html";
  }
}
```

and here is Thymeleaf Template

```
 <table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th th:text="#{msg.id}" />
        <th th:text="#{msg.name}" />
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="book, iStat : ${bookPage.content}"
        th:style="${iStat.odd}? 'font-weight: bold;'"
        th:alt-title="${iStat.even}? 'even' : 'odd'">
        <td th:text="${book.id}" />
        <td th:text="${book.name}" />
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div th:if="${bookPage.totalPages > 0}" class="pagination"
    th:each="pageNumber : ${pageNumbers}">
    <a th:href="@{/listBooks(size=${bookPage.size}, page=${pageNumber})}"
        th:text=${pageNumber}
        th:class="${pageNumber==bookPage.number + 1} ? active"></a>
</div>
```